# Manage controllers with namespace according to user role + cancancan + rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancancan

==> I have a website with two names spaces as below

`User::xyz_controller`

`User::abc_controller`

`Admin:xyz_controller`

`Admin:abc_controller`

==> *User model with three roles*

**`admin 
leader 
consultant`**

If the user has role leader or consultant. He should only access the **User namespace controllers**. and if User has role Admin. Admin should only access the **Admin namespace controllers**.

==> below is my **ability.rb** file content.

`class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability
  def initialize(user)
    if user.has_role? :Admin
      can :manage, :all
    elsif user.has_role? :Leader
      cannot :manage, User
    elsif user.has_role? :Consultant
      cannot :manage, User
    end
end
end`

Answer (score 0):

**Application Controller**

`before_action :current_ability, unless: :devise_controller?`

`private`

`def current_ability`

`controller_name_segments = params[:controller].split('/')`

`controller_name_segments.pop`

`controller_namespace = controller_name_segments.join('/').camelize`

`Ability.new(current_user, controller_namespace)`

`end`

**ability.rb**

`class Ability`

`include CanCan::Ability`

`def initialize(user, namespace)`

`case namespace`

`when 'Admin'`

`can :manage, :dashboard if user.has_role? :Admin`

`can :manage, Company if user.has_role? :Admin`

`can :manage, CompanyHistory if user.has_role? :Admin`

`can :manage, Record if user.has_role? :Admin`

`can :manage, Service if user.has_role? :Admin`

`can :manage, ProcessTable if user.has_role? :Admin`

`can :manage, User if user.has_role? :Admin`

`when 'Users'`

`can :manage, Company if user.has_role? :Consultant`

`can :manage, CompanyHistory if user.has_role? :Consultant`

`can :manage, Record if user.has_role? :Consultant`

`can :manage, Company if  user.has_role? :Leader`

`can :manage, CompanyHistory if user.has_role? :Leader`

`can :manage, Record if  user.has_role? :Leader`

`end`

`end`

`end`

**Define in controller**

--> *Use without class*

`load_and_authorize_resource class: false`

--> *Use with class*

`load_and_authorize_resource class: Company`